# How to set the runtime of an animation based on attack speed?

Tags: animation, unreal-4

**Based on an answer I received on this question:**

[How to make an action perform only after an animation has run?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/175581/how-to-make-an-action-perform-only-after-an-animation-has-run)

I am using notifications in animations to perform certain commands/actions.

**See in the documentation:**

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Animation/Sequences/Notifies/index.html

**Before resorting to this site, I researched elsewhere for something about modifying the animation speed and the closest question I found was this:**

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/509654/how-do-you-change-the-ratespeed-of-animation.html

Simply changing the speed of the animation, I know how to do it, but I want to control its runtime. Sort of determining how much time the animation has to play.

**In the image below I show more or less the scenario I have:**

[image]

Note that the notification happens at the end of the animation (where I apply the damage).

So based on the speed I set for animation to perform, every time it's finished the notification happens, applying the damage.

**It turns out that the animation doesn't necessarily have the exact duration of an attack starting when the other one ends (the image below will make it easier to understand):**

[image]

There is one more scenario I imagined.

**In the latter case, assuming the animation is (usually) 1 second long, and the character has the maximum attack speed (I set the maximum to 2 attacks per second). So the animation would be running 2 times faster:**

[image]

But the attack speed will not always be a "simple" number, I would like to know how to calculate/set it time so I have no problems when the attack speed is any number.

**I want to know how to set the animation runtime and a time interval between the animation running.**

Comment: Divide the wait time by attacks per second modifier. Animation has a “playback speed” property called rate - which you would like to multiply by the attacks per second rate in case your animations are always 1sec long.

Comment: @ColdSteel I modify it where exactly? BP player, BP anim player? Inside or outside the state machine?

Comment: @ColdSteel I saw that you can make this dynamic change in execution speed on the state machine. I happen to need to know the exact animation time at standard speed and I don't know how to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To find out the duration of the animation, just open it and look at this part of the screen:**

[image]

Another way to find out the duration is to divide the total number of frames by the framerate.

**In my case:**

180/24 => 7.5

**In the player animation blueprint on the state machine you will see an option called *Play Rate* (click on the pink circled location in the picture below):**

[image]

**This way you will be able to change the animation speed using the variable and constant values (State Machine):**

[image]